# Conditional logistic regression in SPSS (using multinomial logistic regression)

Tags: regression, spss, logistics

I want to use `NOMREG` of `SPSS` (by GUI from "Regression --> Multinomial Logistic Regression") for my matched data. However, I don't know where to insert the strata variable (the matching variable) into the GUI or syntax.

On a side note, I have a question on conditional logistic regression in `R` that have posted it to the programming branch of the StackExchange because the last time I sent a code-related question here, mods fried me (although I see other people send their `R` code here). Anyways, the address for my `R` question is [this (LINK)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18494133/r-conditional-binary-logistic-regression-syntax-and-debugging).

Comment: I believe this question may belong on SO, too--it's not appropriate here because it is solely about how to control your particular stats program.  You can find good SPSS links at http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/a/807.

Comment: Removed [R] tag and changed the title to reflect the content of this question.

Comment: A quick [search of google](https://www.google.com/search?q=conditional+logistic+regression+SPSS&oq=conditional+logistic+regression+SPSS) brings up a variety of answers. It appears it is simplest to just use `COXREG` with the `STRATA` sub-command.

Comment: You're allowed to post R code at CrossValidated if the fundamental question is about statistics and not the code per se. Also, this question could get closed for being too broad. It's really two.

Comment: Andy W, of course I could do so and I had googled it and had found it. This is exactly why I clearly stated using multinomial logistic regression, not cox regression. But thanks anyway.

Comment: John, I considered asking the same question once for R and once for SPSS double posting. So I wanted to avoid it.

Comment: Whuber, thanks for the link